# Environment status becomes severe when second environment is deployed

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, development-environment, production-environment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I uploaded sample django project to AWS using elasticbeanstalk.
I deployed two environments accoding to a tutorial here https://colintoh.com/blog/how-to-deploy-application-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk.

When I deployed(create using eb cli) the second environment, the first environment helth changes to sever showing errors on elasticbeanstak console

```
100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (12.0 requests/min) to determine application health.
ELB processes are not healthy on all instances.
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
```

However when I access both pages they seem to be working correctly since they both show django's debug message for first page

```
The install worked successfully! Congratulations!
You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs.
```

Can I just ignore the error or I need to do something to fix the error(and how to fix it)?

Answer (score 0):

Normal behaviour on applications with zero traffic.
A little more advanced but you could add a healtcheck path to your loadbalancer, it will generate 'some' traffic.

Also in the console there is an option (environment -> configuration -> monitoring) to ignore 4XX error's.

Comment: I have two environments with same config and same project and one of the other's health is green so app with zero traffic can have green health.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Elastic Beanstalk checks the health of your environment by sending a request to `/` path and expects it return a `200` code. 
Maybe this route does not exist on your project. 
If you need to, you can configure the path where EB will send a request to check the health. In the configuration panel of your environment, go to Load Balancer and edit the default process to change the `Health check path`.